# Longest pair of string elements or longest side of the pairs in Bash array

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, string-length

Given an array in Bash:

```sh
my_array=("a" "b"    "a bc" "d"    "ab" "cd")
```

Considering each two consecutive items in the array as a `pair`, how can I:

- Get the length of the longest pair. In the example above it would be `"a bc" "d"`, so length `5`.
- Get the length of the longest of the fist items in the pairs. Above would be `"a bc"`, so length `4`.
- Get the length of the longest of the second items in the pairs. Above would be `"cd"`, so length `2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to use a `for` loop that increments an index variable by 2 every time. Everything else is basic parameter expansion to get the lengths of elements and tests against the current maximums.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -a my_array=("a" "b"    "a bc" "d"    "ab" "cd")
declare -i maxlen_combo=0 maxlen_first=0 maxlen_second=0

IFS=""
for (( i = 0; i < ${#my_array[@]}; i += 2 )); do
    if [[ $maxlen_first -lt ${#my_array[i]} ]]; then
        maxlen_first=${#my_array[i]}
    fi
    if [[ $maxlen_second -lt ${#my_array[i+1]} ]]; then
        maxlen_second=${#my_array[i+1]}
    fi
    combo="${my_array[*]:i:2}"
    if [[ $maxlen_combo -lt ${#combo} ]]; then
        maxlen_combo=${#combo}
    fi
done

echo "Maximum pair length: $maxlen_combo"
echo "Maximum first length: $maxlen_first"
echo "Maximum second length: $maxlen_second"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
printf "%s\n" ${my_array[@]} |
awk '{itemlen=length($0)}
     NR%2==1 {
              firstmaxlen = (itemlen > firstmaxlen) ? itemlen : firstmaxlen;
              firsthalf=itemlen
             }
     NR%2==0 {
              secondmaxlen = (itemlen > secondmaxlen) ? itemlen : secondmaxlen;
              pairlen = (firsthalf + itemlen > pairlen ) ? firsthalf + itemlen : pairlen ;
             }
      END { printf ("maxcombo, maxfirst, maxsecond) = (%d, %d, %d)\n", 
            pairlen, firstmaxlen, secondmaxlen) }
    '
```

In this case a small function can help:

```
printf "%s\n" ${my_array[@]} |
awk 'function max(a,b) { return (a>b ? a : b) }
     {itemlen=length($0)}
     NR%2==1 {
              firstmaxlen = max(itemlen, firstmaxlen);
              firsthalf=itemlen
             }
     NR%2==0 {
              secondmaxlen = max(itemlen, secondmaxlen);
              pairlen = max(firsthalf + itemlen, pairlen);
             }
      END { printf ("maxcombo, maxfirst, maxsecond) = (%d, %d, %d)\n", 
                   pairlen, firstmaxlen, secondmaxlen) }
    '
```